# GoLand not detecting vendor packages under $GOPATH/pkg/mod?

Tags: go, build, goland, go-modules

Goland not detecting the imported modules from github.com. The modules are available in $GOPATH/pkg/mod directory but the imports are not being resolved. The vendor directory also have all the packages downloaded.

Goland Version : 2019.3.3 
Go Version : Go 1.13.7

**Under Preferences:**

```
 - GOROOT is set to /usr/local/go
 - Global GOPATH is set to /Users/xyz/go
 - Go module integration is enabled
 - Enable vendoring support is enabled. 
 - dep integration is not enabled.
```

Project Structure :

```
- project-name
  - bin
  - build
  - cmd
     - serviced
        - main.go
  - internal 
    - config
      - config.go
  - vendor
    - github.com
      - .....
  - go.mod 

- External Libraries
  - GO SDK 1.13.7
```

Worth mentioning that, Goland is not downloading the Go modules under External libraries.

Comment: We've recently fixed some related bugs. Could you please update to 2019.3.4? Does it help?

Comment: $GOPATH/pkg/mod is entirely unrelated to vendoring.

Answer (score 2):

Download all `src` of libraries to `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`

```
go mod download
```

Create `vendor` directory (`<project-name>/vendor`) use `vendor` *flag*

```
go mod vendor
```

**Before 1.14 version**

Build with `vendor` *flag*

```
go build -mod=vendor
```

or

```
GOFLAGS="-mod=vendor" go build
```

**1.14 and  higher** ([Go Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules))

> When the main module contains a top-level `vendor` directory and its `go.mod` file specifies go 1.14 or higher, the go command now defaults to `-mod=vendor` for operations that accept that flag. A new value for that flag, `-mod=mod`, causes the go command to instead load modules from the module cache (as when no vendor directory is present).

*Execute in `project-name` directory ( which contains `go.mod`)*